# bad alloc exception from parallel algorithms when compiling with -fno-exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, c++17

For various reasons the code i'm working with is compiled using the `-fno-exceptions` option in MingW GCC 11.2. In certain places i'd like to make use of the parallel algorithms from C++17. However, when attempting to use those algorithms with policy set to `std::execution::par`, i get errors trying to compile: `error: exception handling disabled, use '-fexceptions' to enable` because of `catch (const std::bad_alloc&)` from `utils.h`.

Am i doomed to not being able to use those algorithms unless i enable exceptions?

Comment: Yes. They allocate memory and throw exceptions if that fails. That's the end of it.

Comment: I'm afraid that by compiling without exception you make the conscious choice of rejecting most of standard library, as it can throw exceptions. Maybe you could compile it in a separate dynamic library that you will compile with exceptions, and you would catch them and turn into error codes?